# SwiftUI "un-bind" a string from a textfield

Tags: ios, realm, swiftui, xcode11.4

I’m trying to store a string from a textfield into a Realm DB. Somehow it doesn't save just the actual string, instead it saves some kind of metatext from the binding:

> *Binding(transaction: SwiftUI.Transaction(plist: []),
>   location: SwiftUI.StoredLocation, _value: "**John
>   Doe**")*

How can I just save the entered string to realm without the infos surrounding it?

This is my code:

`@State var enteredName: String = ""
let realm = try! Realm()`

for the textfield:

```
TextField("enter your name", text: $enteredName)
   .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
```

and for the button:

```
Button(action: {

    let newPerson = Contacts()
    newPerson.name = "\(self.$enteredName)"

    do {
        try self.realm.write {
            self.realm.add(newPerson)
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error saving newPerson \(error)")
    } 
}) {
    Text("Save New Person")   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `Button` closure, `action`, by using the `$` symbol you are sending a binding reference to `enteredName`.  You simply need a normal reference, which you can do by removing the `$` symbol.

Your code should be:

```
Button(action: {

    let newPerson = Contacts()
    newPerson.name = self.enteredName

    do {
        try self.realm.write {
            self.realm.add(newPerson)
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error saving newPerson \(error)")
    } 
}) {
    Text("Save New Person")   
}
```

Comment: That was surprisedly easy, thanks @joseph0x4365732E !

Comment: No problem, @Daniel.  Glad I could help.